# How to show data from JSON file to Bootstrap 4 Carousel using jQuery including images hash

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, bootstrap-4

I am trying to parse a JSON file from my locally json and in **console.log** I am getting the array but I do not know how to put in the Bootstrap carousel to show the data.
I want to get thee JSON files and to show in carousel only thee JSON which starts with tag data
Here you can find the JSON files 
[JSON files](https://jsfiddle.net/q79gm8vL/)
I tried something like this till now.
Depends on the answer of the @T.Shah everything it is working one problem it is that the first item it is blank and then it is taking the JSON data, I tried to remove the `carousel-item active` but then it is showing anything.
Code is updated.

```
$.getJSON('./data/projects.json', {get_param: 'value'}, function (getArray) {
        $.each(getArray.data, function (index, element) {
            var thisImage = element.image;
            $('.carousel-inner').append('<div class="carousel-item">' +
                '<img class="d-block w-100" src="https://demo.test.com/api/v4/media/' + thisImage + '/thumbnail/width/900/height/600/strategy/crop" alt="">' +
                '<div class="carousel-caption">' +
                '<h3>' + element.name + '</h3>' +
                '<p>' + element.description + '</p>' +
                '</div>' + '</div>');
        });
    });
<div id="carouselExampleControls" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
        <div class="carousel-item active">
        </div>

    </div>
    <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#carouselExampleControls" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
    </a>
</div>
```

Comment: `$('#test')` what is the element with id "test"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are appending to id named 'test', when carousel does not have that id at all.  I modified your script and it adds items to the carousel.

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            var itemClass;
            $.getJSON('./data/projects.json', {get_param: 'value'}, function (getArray) {
                $.each(getArray.data, function (index, element) {
                    var totalItems = $(".carousel-item").length;
                    if(totalItems === 0) {
                        itemClass = "carousel-item active";
                    }
                    else {
                        itemClass = "carousel-item";
                    }
                    console.log(totalItems);
                    var thisImage = element.image;
                    $('.carousel-inner').append('<div class="'+itemClass+'">' +
                        '<img class="d-block w-100" src="https://demo.test.com/api/v4/media/' + thisImage + '/thumbnail/width/900/height/600/strategy/crop" alt="">' +
                        '<div class="carousel-caption">' +
                        '<h3>' + element.name + '</h3>' +
                        '<p>' + element.description + '</p>' +
                        '</div>' + '</div>');
                });
            });
    })
    </script>
```

Comment: and how to show the images because they are hashed ?
I do have the link to unhash them.
`https://demo.[staging.]test.com/api/v4/media/**HASH**/thumbnail/width/**WIDTH**/height/**HEIGHT**/strategy/crop`

Comment: I have edited the answer to include image. Unfortunately I do not know how to unhash them.

Comment: thanks man I am trying to unhash them but why always the first elemeent that is active it is blank and then starts to show the array ?

Comment: I am able to unhash the images but they are appearing not so good in style very big and not compatible with the screen.
I have made something like this
`https://demo.test.com/api/v4/media/'+thisImage+'/thumbnail/width/1200/height/500/strategy/crop"`
How to add text into the image do you know ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by adding text to image.  I have edited the answer to incorporate a few attributes in the image tag like class, height, width and title.  You will have to pass value to imgWidth and imgHeight variables.

Comment: I have everything fixed but one problem always the carousel it creates first item blank and then it is showing the data from json.
See the edited question.

Comment: Instead of keeping an empty carousel item with active class, use jquery to determine whether the current item is the first one or not.  If it is the first one, then apply class active to it otherwise don't.

Answer (score 1):

First of all make sure you use strict mode on the global module scope,
you json data is a little complex for demonstration but i'm sure you can iterate over objects and arrays so let's assume this is the json file that we have:

```
{
   "items" : [
  {
   "img": "assets/owl1.jpg",
   "alt" : "Owl Image 1"
  },
  {
   "img": "assets/owl2.jpg",
   "alt" : "Owl Image 2"
  },
  {
   "img": "assets/owl3.jpg",
   "alt" : "Owl Image 1"
  },
 ]
}
```

Are you using a carousel plugin or a custom one ?! i recommend you to use owlcarousel.
import you custom json to owlcarousel like this :

```
$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
  jsonPath : 'json/customData.json',
  jsonSuccess : customDataSuccess
});
```

then create the customDataSuccess like this :

```
function customDataSuccess(data){
 var content = "";
 for(var i in data["items"]){

   var img = data["items"][i].img;
   var alt = data["items"][i].alt;

   content += "<img src=\"" +img+ "\" alt=\"" +alt+ "\">"
 }
 $("#owl-demo").html(content);
}
```

owl-demo is a div in html were the carousel will leave:

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
</div>
```

Comment: I am not using the carousel plugin, Im using custom one with link from bootstrap 4.

Comment: I have fix it and it all works but with a problem it is adding at first a blank carousel and then it is going to show the parsedJSON.